# Magento 2.3.4 wrong order date in invoice PDF

Tags: php, magento2

As already said in the title, when I check the order date in the Magento2 backend, it shows the correct date, but when I look at the order date in the invoice PDF, it shows something completely different:

Here's the backend part:

[image]

Here's my invoice

[image]

I already had a look at several similar questions but nothing helped me so far. I am using the de_DE locale. I also checked the timezone, but it's all configured correctly. If further information are needed, I will provide them.

Answer (score 4):

The same issue for me and solve with this code fix
Navigation to this file `/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php`

and Replaced this function to :

```
public function scopeDate($scope = null, $date = null, $includeTime = false)
    {
        $timezone = new \DateTimeZone(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue($this->getDefaultTimezonePath(), $this->_scopeType, $scope)
        );
        switch (true) {
            case (empty($date)):
                $date = new \DateTime('now', $timezone);
                break;
            case ($date instanceof \DateTime):
            case ($date instanceof \DateTimeImmutable):
                $date = $date->setTimezone($timezone);
                break;
            default:
                $date = new \DateTime(is_numeric($date) ? '@' . $date : $date);
                $date->setTimezone($timezone);
                break;
        }

        if (!$includeTime) {
            $date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        }

        return $date;
    }
```

Run the command and check your result

Comment: Still present in Magento 2.3.7, this fixes the bug.